# Substituting an even function for an odd function in an integral

Tags: integration

In a book I am reading it says while evaluating an integral it says you cannot substitute an odd function for an even function of another variable ( for example substituting sinx with cosu and integrating with respect to u) if the domain of integration of original integral contains 0.

Why is this so? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide an explicit example?

Comment: http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~kdjoshi/jee2014.pdf

Comment: See problem 46 of paper 2 in the above link

Comment: why are you studying this, are you preparing for jee advanced on may 24 like me?

Comment: Are you in 12th?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For: $0<a<b$ we have:
$$
\int_{-a}^b f(x)dx=\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx+\int_{a}^b f(x)dx
$$
If $f(-x)=-f(x)$ is odd 
$$
\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx=\int_{-a}^0 f(x)dx +\int_{0}^a f(x)dx=\int_{0}^a f(-x)dx+\int_{0}^a f(x)dx=0
$$

but this is no true (in general) if $f(x)$ is not an odd function.

Answer (score -1):

I think the paper mentions the reason as well:

> ... because
>   in that case a substitution by an even function would not work since
>   an even function cannot assume both positive and negative values.

Comment: That's the part I don't understand